# Using user input function in Classes

Tags: python, object, oop, input

I am making a simple game with multiple players, which each player can insert their first name, last name and each player is assigned 100 poins at the begging. In my code once I am done with coding the "essential" information, but when it comes to user input it does not work.

The "base" for the player class:  (this part works)

```
class Players(): 
    def __init__ (self, firstname, lastname, coins):   #initialising attributes
        self.firstname = firstname
        
        self.lastname = lastname
        
        self.coins= coins
   
    def full_info(self):
      return self.firstname  + self.lastname + self.coins
```

This is the second part where the problem is, the input is not stored in the attributes

```
  def get_user_input(self):
        firstname= input("Please enter your first name:")
        lastname= input ("Please enter your second name: ")
        coins= 100 #they are assigned automatically 
        return self(firstname, lastname, coins)
```

I would appriciate any suggesting regarding the user input.

Comment: Create your [mcve] and add to your question,

Comment: You never store the info into the attributes... Perhaps you could place your input lines into the __init__ method and store them into the attributes at this time

Answer (score 2):

Your function to build a new instance from user input should be a `classmethod` or a `staticmethod`, since you want to call it to create a new instance.

I'd also suggest using `@dataclass` so you don't need to copy and paste all the variable names in `__init__`, and using an f-string in your `full_info` function so you don't hit an error when you try to add `coins` to the name strings.

All together it might look like:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Player: 
    firstname: str
    lastname: str
    coins: int

    def full_info(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.firstname} {self.lastname} {self.coins}"

    @classmethod
    def from_user_input(cls) -> 'Player':
        return cls(
            firstname=input("Please enter your first name:"),
            lastname=input("Please enter your second name: "),
            coins=100,
        )
```

Then you can call `Player.from_user_input()` to prompt the user for a name and return a new `Player` object:

```
>>> player = Player.from_user_input()
Please enter your first name:Bob
Please enter your second name: Small
>>> player
Player(firstname='Bob', lastname='Small', coins=100)
>>> player.full_info()
'Bob Small 100'
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, 
for player 1 I would do this:  player1 = Player.from_user_input()
Player(firstname='', lastname='', coins=100)
print(player1)
 and then for the player 2 I would change player 1 to player 2?

Comment: I like this method, is it possible to simplyfy it a bit? 
Especially the part with with "str". In my case, it might be better to use more beggining approach

Comment: `player1, player2 = Player.from_user_input(), Player.from_user_input()` gets you 2 players.  I'm not sure what you mean by "simplify" -- there might be some new concepts in here for you, but if you're a beginner the whole point of doing exercises like this is to learn things.  :)  If you encounter a concept that's confusing, it's more productive to ask "how does this work" than to ask "how do I do it without this" -- the other way might just be more complicated!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay close to your original code, a few changes will work:

```
class Players(): 
    def __init__ (self, firstname, lastname, coins):   #initialising attributes
        self.firstname = firstname  
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.coins= coins
   
    def full_info(self):
      return self.firstname  + ' ' + self.lastname + ' ' + str(self.coins)
  
def get_user_input():
        firstname= input("Please enter your first name:")
        lastname= input ("Please enter your second name: ")
        coins= 100 #they are assigned automatically 
        return Players(firstname, lastname, coins)
```

An example:

```
a=get_user_input()

Please enter your first name:UN

Please enter your second name: Owen

a.full_info()
Out[21]: 'UN Owen 100'
```

Comment: Or just use `self.firstname = input ...` etc. No return required,

Comment: Thank you for your reposne! It did work. I have a question regarding other players. If person "a" is the first person, for the second person i would do the same but change a (to b, for exmaple)?

Comment: Yes; and if you want to do several (let's say n) players, you could use a list instead: n = number_of_players ; l_players = [] ; for i in range(n): l_players.append(get_user_input())

Comment: @user19077881: you're right, provided get_user_input() is defined as a method of the Players class; here I kept it an outside function (to stay close to the original code).

Comment: Hello; having to follow a link to outside code is kinda painful; please make this into a new question :)